# Where to handle Parsing of Floating Point Number - Scanner or Parser?

Tags: parsing, floating-point, bison, flex-lexer

I'm in the process of designing a small domain specific language.
As scanner/parser generators I use Flex/Bisonc++.
Now, the generated DSL-compiler frontend is capable of parsing octal, decimal and hex numbers.
The only thing remaining is the support for floating point numbers (FPN) as notated in C/C++.

There's a RegExp for the floating point number syntax at
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Literals/Floating_point#C

a) I know that parsing that can be done in the scanner or/and in the parser,
but I don't know what's best - in terms of performance and efficiency.

b) One additional constraint is, that I want to avoid touching each character of the input more than once, i.e. I want to avoid using STL or other string-to-float conversion functions
by implementing an on-the-fly conversion during the parsing process.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly feasible, and normally sensible, to have the scanner (`flex` code) recognize and convert the floating point numbers, just as it should be recognizing and converting the integers.  If you've written the integer recognition code in the grammar (`bison` code) rather than the scanner, then maybe you write the floating-point recognition there too, but it is not the way it is normally done.  You will probably need to use a more sophisticated (read 'complex') data type for the token types; read up on `%union`.

Comment: The integer recognition resides in the scanner, so should the FPN recognition according to clean design.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on the following: While I could implement it in the scanner, it would introduce a lot of complexity to the scanner spec (involving a lot of state-handling), whereas an implementation in the parser might be easer. However, since the integer recognition resides in the scanner, so should the FPN recognition to have a clean design. The question I have to meet a decision is: What about execution performance? Is a scanner-based or a parser-based FPN recognition faster?

Comment: Ignore performance; you probably won't be able to measure the difference. If you can, it will be because the grammar code is smaller when the scanner is handling the FPN recognition (the grammar doesn't have to deal with the mess). If you punt the FPN recognition to the grammar, your scanner will have to return `-23.00456E+34` as 5 separate tokens (`-23`, `.`, `00456`, `E` and `+34`, preserving leading zeroes. You will sometimes have to process a character twice; pushback is inevitable (you need to read one character beyond the end of the number to know you have reached the end, for example).